# jQuery var addition per row

Tags: jquery, each

I have a section in a form of inputs, quanitity, price and tax.

I can add them together for 1 row fine, where I get stuck is per additional row.

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q1bL94jt/1/

html:

```
<div class="prod-row-wrap">
 <div class="prod-new-row">
  <div class="prod-name">
   <select class="form-control" name="prod_name[]">
    <option value="x">Platinum subscription</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  <div class="prod-quan">
   <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="prod-price">
    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="prod-tax">
    <input type="text" name="tax" class="form-control" />
  </div>
  <div class="prod-total">
    <p>&pound; <span class="total">0</span></p>
  </div>
  <div class="prod-delete">
    <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-lg add_product_button">Add product</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('[name="tax"]').on('input', function() {
 var quantity = $('[name="quantity"]').val();
 var price = $('[name="price"]').val();
 var tax = $('[name="tax"]').val();
 var subtotal = quantity * price;
 var tax_total = (subtotal / 100) * tax;
 var total = subtotal + tax_total;
 $('.total').text(total);
});
```

My amended code (which doesn't work) is:

```
$('.prod-new-row').each(function() {
 $('[name="tax"]', this).on('input', function() {
  var quantity = $('[name="quantity"]').val();
  var price = $('[name="price"]' ).val();
  var tax = $('[name="tax"]').val();
  var subtotal = quantity * price;
  var tax_total = (subtotal / 100) * tax;
  var total = subtotal + tax_total;
  $('.total').text(total);
 });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  In what specific way does this code fail?

Comment: It only adds the prices up for the first row, nothing happens on the second row - see https://jsfiddle.net/q1bL94jt/2/

Comment: I think you need use `parseInt`

Comment: Note: Even after correcting the event binding as per the linked duplicate, there's at least another error in this code as well.  When you have multiple inputs with the same name, which one do you expect something like `$('[name="quantity"]').val()` to get?  You need to specify which one you want, likely as a DOM traversal relative to the element invoking the event.